# How to get id from json but not showing in spinner?

Tags: android, json

I have this `json` from web service :

```
[{"id_mata_kul":"2","mata_kul":"Oracle Database"},{"id_mata_kul":"3","mata_kul":"Pengatar Manajemen dan Bisnis"},{"id_mata_kul":"5","mata_kul":"Leadership"}]
```

then I can displaying the `mata_kul` object in spinner, but I need to get the id from `mata_kul` without displaying the id into spinner,

**Problem :**

I need to save the id depend of `mata_kul` selected.

for the example : when `Leadership` selected from spinner, I need to save that `id 5` using intent. as well as the other, when `Oracle Database` selected from spinner, i need to save `id 2` using intent,

I have read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34564440/how-to-get-selected-spinner-items-id-from-json-response) that had a same issue like me, but I don't know how it works,

can someone help me how to fix the issue?

**EDIT :**

in `doInBackground` :

```
for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {
    JSONObject jsonObject = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
    list2.add(jsonObject.getString("mata_kul")); //collecting all json `mata_kul`
}
```

in `onPostExecute` :

```
listItems2.addAll(list2);
adapter2.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

in `onCreate` :

```
adapter2= new ArrayAdapter<>(this, R.layout.spinner_layout, R.id.txt, listItems2);
```

Comment: Can you show how you have implemented your Spinner adapter?

Comment: convert you JSON to Java model, and you can do anything with it.

Comment: where is your model class

Comment: refer this answer  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37940115/how-could-we-pass-a-different-value-on-an-item-select-from-android-spinner-than/37940347#37940347

Answer (score 1):

Try this way to get id

```
mySpinner
                    .setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0,
                                View arg1, int position, long arg3) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                            // Locate the textviews in activity_main.xml
                            TextView txtrank = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.rank);
                            TextView txtcountry = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.country);
                            TextView txtpopulation = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.population);

                            // Set the text followed by the position 
                            txtrank.setText("Rank : "
                                    + world.get(position).getRank());
                            txtcountry.setText("Country : "
                                    + world.get(position).getCountry());
                            txtpopulation.setText("Population : "
                                    + world.get(position).getPopulation());
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        }
                    });
        }
    }
```

http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/android-populating-spinner-json-tutorial/

Comment: i think that's not what i need, because i can't use `position` to get the id,

Comment: because you are not using POJO classs/Model class

Comment: as u can see in my json, i have 3 data, but the id is constant, depending of what `mata_kul` selected

Comment: i don't see the POJO class in that site anyway, :(

Comment: create model class with name WorldPopulation

Answer (score 0):

You could solve your issue by using Hashmap. Store your id value as key and mata_kul part as value in the Hashmap. Then use the Hashmap values to show in spinner. When an item is clicked, find the corresponding id from the hashmap using the value.

Answer (score 0):

Override Spinner OnItemclickListener and get the selected item position

```
spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
       @Override
       public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    int selectedItemPos = position;
    //use selectedItemPos to retrieve id values from json array 
}
```

Comment: i can't do that, because when `Leadership` selected, the id value is 3, but in my json, `leadership` id should 5

Comment: If you store your data in an Array you can easily retrieve using position.

Answer (score 0):

First, create a model to store json value from the web service.
Then create custom adapter with this model.
And handle spinner's item selected event:

```
spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
     Model model = (Model) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
     // do something with the model
}
@Override
public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

}});
```